# Calling value of textbox in Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying simply to get Visual Basic to read the textbox and set the value to a variable, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

**HTML:**

```html
<body>
    <script>
        function myfn() {
            alert(<%= myInputAge%>)
        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox id="av10test" runat="server" Text="hello"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" onclick=myfn() value="hello"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code Behind:**

```vb
Partial Class WebForm7
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            myInputAge = av10test.Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Property myInputAge

End Class
```

Comment: How are u defining `myInputAge`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I set it as protected property. When I replace av10test.Text with a string, the alert works fine, so I don't know if defining the variable is the issue.

Comment: Your VB source only declares `myInputAge`, but it does not provide a definition. That will give you a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.NET if you define a property, you have to define its GET and SET methods. As it is you can define a field:

```
Protected myInputAge As String
```

Couple more changes: You have to include function call for onlclick in quotes:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myfn()" value="hello"/>
```

and encase output of <%= %> into quotes as well

```
 function myfn() {
            alert('<%= myInputAge%>')
 }
```